# Testprintenv:error while loading shared libraries:libodbc.so.1: cannot open shared object file

Tags: linux, dynamic-linking, shared-library

I am trying to invoke a C-Program which returns the value for a given keyword from a configuration file

While trying to invoke program it's displaying below error:

```
**Testprintenv: error while loading shared libraries: libodbc.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**
```

We have installed EasySoft previously and uninstalled back (Removed all directories).

Below dependencies are showing up on Linux machine

```
-bash-4.1$ ldd Testprintenv
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffc0bdb000)
        libodbc.so.1 => not found
        libodbcinst.so.1 => not found
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x000000397b200000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000397ae00000)
```

When we try the same program on Solaris machine dependencies are showing up differently and executing without any error:

```
[Testuser]$ ldd Testprintenv
        libsocket.so.1 =>        /lib/libsocket.so.1
        libnsl.so.1 =>   /lib/libnsl.so.1
        libc.so.1 =>     /lib/libc.so.1
        libmp.so.2 =>    /lib/libmp.so.2
        libmd.so.1 =>    /lib/libmd.so.1
        libscf.so.1 =>   /lib/libscf.so.1
        libdoor.so.1 =>  /lib/libdoor.so.1
        libuutil.so.1 =>         /lib/libuutil.so.1
        libgen.so.1 =>   /lib/libgen.so.1
        libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2
        /platform/SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise/lib/libc_psr.so.1
```

Any insight why the dependency (libodbc.so.1) is only showing up on Linux and how to resolve?

Comment: Can you give code of `Testprintenv` program?

Comment: Check for broken packages in your OS. For deciban `sudo apt-get install`

Comment: What command is used to invoke the c program ? Can you show that program ?

Answer (score 1):

it appears that the odbc library has not been installed on your Linux system.  use the appropriate package management system to add the library.  here are a couple commands that would work for some common distributions:

for an RPM managed system like Centos, Redhat, or Fedora:

```
sudo yum install unixODBC
```

for a debian system like Ubuntu or Mint:

```
sudo apt-get install libodbc1
```